# How to update items for a day in mongoose/mongodb from UTC to local time

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to update Journal logs for each day, but I am getting confused on how to use UTC vs local time. I am using Moment.js to try and find journal entries from the start of a day to the end of day in local time, and upsert a new entry for that day if it doesn't exist. MongoDB stores data in UTC time. I was able to get it working when I had it set up as a local server, but when I deployed to Heroku it doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
 await Journal.findOneAndUpdate(
      {
        journal_date: {
          $gte: moment().startOf("day").toString(),
          $lte: moment().endOf("day").toString(),
        }
      },
      {
        journal_date: new Date().toISOString(),
        $push: {
           data: data
        },
      },
      { upsert: true, new: true }
    );
```

The code should basically check to see if there is a journal entry which exists from start of day to end of day (local time). It then upserts the data and uses current date as the new journal date.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"?

Comment: I changed the code a few times, but this is the latest version that I have. I always have to wait for different times in the day to test and haven't been able to get it to work. I updated the items yesterday, and when I tried another update this morning it combined todays entries with yesterday's entries as Oct 4th.

Comment: Maybe set your current locale with [Locale Buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-locale)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is usually a design flaw to store Date/Time value as string, you should never do that.

I don't think `.toString()` is what you ar looking for, it returns a string like `Sat Apr 30 2016 16:59:46 GMT-0500`, try `.toDate()`

You are right, MongoDB stores data in UTC time - always and only. Typically the client is responsible to *display* the date in local times. All operations and comparisons are done in UTC.

The solution might be this one:

```
Journal.findOneAndUpdate(
  {
    journal_date: {
      $gte: moment.tz("Europe/Zurich").startOf("day").toDate(),
      $lte: moment.tz("Europe/Zurich").endOf("day").toDate(),
    }
  },
  {
    journal_date: new Date(),
    $push: {
       data: data
    },
  },
  { upsert: true, new: true }
);
```

Actually, `moment().startOf("day").toDate()` should also work, it returns the current **local** time. However, perhaps Heroku sets the current locale to different value, so you many get something else.

Have a look at your `TZ` environment variable, this defines the local time zone:

```
$ export TZ="America/Havana"
$ mongo --nodb <<< "moment().format()"
MongoDB shell version v4.4.0
Loaded Moment
2020-10-06T02:38:01-04:00
bye
```

However, there might be other settings which may takes precedence, you have to test.

Comment: I tried using moment().startOf("day").toDate(), but I ended up getting the data from yesterday added to today (it could be because of the way it was formatted last night).

Comment: Thanks for your help, I went ahead and used moment timezone moment.tz("America/Los_Angeles").endOf("day").toDate(), and it seems to be working based off the console logs I added. However, this will only work at one timezone. Do you know how I can make it dynamic for all timezones if I wanted to upgrade in the future so that it can work everywhere?

Comment: The time zone is a normal parameter, set it in your application.